# Making title unique using hook_entity_bundle_field_info_alter()

Tags: hooks, 8

`hook_node_validate()` is replaced by `hook_entity_bundle_field_info_alter()` in Drupal 8.

I need to validate the **node title** whether the same **title** is used in any other node. Title field should be unique for me.

How can I define that in `hook_entity_bundle_field_info_alter()`? When I print something in this hook. It didn't called when I save the node.

```
function my_module_entity_bundle_field_info_alter(&$fields, \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface $entity_type, $bundle) {
  if ($entity_type->id() == 'node') {
    dpm($entity_type);
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you rebuild your cache? Can you please post your code too?

Comment: Yes I cleared the cache. I updated the question with the code to print something in the hook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This hook only runs with a cold cache.
In Drupal 8 validation is done with plugins.

When this hook runs for the node entity type, you will have an array of fields, one of which is title. You need to define a new validation constraint plugin. Model it on the unique feed title or unique username one and that way you'll only have to write one method and a property or two.
Take note of your plugin's ID. When you're in that hook, call addConstraint on the title field, passing your plugin ID.

I have a feeling there's another hook too, maybe hook_entity_base_field_info_alter, but I could be wrong there. If you don't see title in the field list, check the api docs for a hook with base field in the name

Comment: After reading your answer I checked forum module which used `hook_entity_bundle_field_info_alter` and I looked at the plugin created by it. I couldn't understand what it does and how to implement the plugin. can you please explain further?

Answer (score 0):

You can check too node title validation
https://www.drupal.org/project/node_title_validation

This module do this, you can see the way or reuse de module.